# Reading multiple files "except IOError as exc:"

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, glob, errno, ioerror

I was **looking** through **some example** of how to **read multiple files of data** and **come across these codes** pop-up a lot:

```
try:
    ...
except IOError as exc:
    if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
        raise
```

But I **couldn't see anyone trying to explain** it so I was hoping if you guys can help me to understand what it is?

Here is an **example**:

```
import glob
import errno

...

#Create a list of the path of all .txt files
files_list = glob.glob(data_path)

#Iterate through the files in files_list
for file_name in files_list:
    try:
        #something

    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we'll go through these lines of code one by one.

```
except IOError as exc:
```

The above line just catches an exception and gets the error message in the variable `exc`. What the exception means is along the lines of

> when a system function returns a system-related error, including I/O failures such as “file not found” or “disk full” (not for illegal argument types or other incidental errors). [Python 3 Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError)

Note in Python 3, this is now `OSError` as `IOError` is merged into it.

```
    if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
```

This line will check the type of error. This is given by the error's `errno` attribute. Specifically, `errno.EISDIR` means the error given came because the 'file' was actually a folder / directory. More info can be found [here :D](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/errno.html).

```
        raise
```

Now the if statement has gone through and checked the type of error. It only lets it through to the `raise` over here if the error type does NOT mean that the path given was a directory. This means the exception could mean anything from 'Permission Denied' to 'Out of Memory'.

Hope that helped you out :D